# Configuring passenger_wsgi.py to use Pelican

Tags: python, passenger, pelican

I've been trying to configure python environment to use Pelican for static blogging. This is a common setting for Django, so I'm wondering what I need to put in so it can start using Pelican.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/DjangoProjects')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'example_com.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Btw, my server works fine with this setting.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
return ["Hello, world!"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelican is a static blog generator, **static** means once generated, the content is stored in files and won't change. Tt's different from Django, which dynamiclly generates the content whenever a user visit your blog.

So, all you have to do is copying the files from `output` folder to a document root folder of a web server like `apache` or `nginx`.

Or, you can simply type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in terminal, and you can visit your blog at `http://localhost:8000/`. (executing `make serve` in you pelican blog folder will do the same.). This works well for development.

Or, you can use github to serve your blog, see: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.1.1/tips.html#publishing-to-github